# JMX enabled Java application appears to open a random high order port when JMX client connects

Tags: java, random, port, jmx, firewall

## JMX enabled Java application appears to open a random high order port when JMX client connects

I have successfully configured a helloworld JMX enabled program, and I can connect to it using jconsole JMX client from a remote location.

When I attempt to turn on iptables I noticed that a random high order port is established when a client logs in.  Eventually I would like to monitor Java applications in firewall segregated network segments.  Can we control the range the random port opens in?

I'll move this question to serverfault.com if suggested.

Comment: The port is established on client or server? If on client I suppose it's the client port bound to the server port...

Comment: Interesting question you pose.  The JMX client connects to the JMX server over a port defined by the server.  After this happens another (random?) port opens and is used to communicate.

Comment: So this port is on the client or on the server?

Comment: This random port opens on the server hosting the JMX enabled application (server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to control the port used by RMI.  See: http://olegz.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/jmx-connectivity-through-the-firewall/

This requires code and a command-line parameter.  There's no way that I know of to do this without code (though the code can obviously be packaged in a different jar).

Comment: I found this blog post helpful as well http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 7u25 the RMI port can be changed with a system property:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1234
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552812/3790806) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Random third port seems to be expected behavior https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035404

Answer (score 0):

by the way, this third ephemeral port can be controlled too - https://www.paybackblog.de/java-jmx-how-to-finally-control-your-ports/

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to set the RMI port the same as the JMX port; then only that one port needs to be open on the Firewall.

For example:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8989
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8989
```

See [Why Java opens 3 ports when JMX is configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884353/why-java-opens-3-ports-when-jmx-is-configured/21552812#21552812)