# Tomcat7 with enabled JMX opens 2 additional random listening ports

Tags: java, security, tomcat7, port, jmx

I run Tomcat7 using JDK7 on Centos6.
I enable JMX using the following options:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9123 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true"
```

Unfortunately, when I check what ports are opened I discover 2 additional random ports:

```
netstat -plunt | grep java
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::60555                            :::*                LISTEN      22752/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080               :::*                LISTEN      22752/java
tcp        0      0 :::9123                             :::*                LISTEN      22752/java
tcp        0      0 :::40867                            :::*                LISTEN      22752/java
```

I guess that JMX should open one additional port [JMX enabled Java application appears to open a random high order port when JMX client connects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163173/jmx-enabled-java-application-appears-to-open-a-random-high-order-port-when-jmx-c)

Why JMX in Tomcat opens 2 additional ports?

How can I configure these ports?

If I configure `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true` means additional ports also can be accessed using local access only?

How can I configure `::ffff:127.0.0.1` will appear before all ports opened by JMX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tomcat's [JMX Remote Lifecycle Listener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener) which allows fixing the ports used by the JMX/RMI Server.
The JMX Remote Lifecycle Listener allows configuring the following ports:

- `rmiRegistryPortPlatform`    - The port to be used by the JMX/RMI registry
  for the Platform MBeans. This one should be used instead of the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` system property
- `rmiServerPortPlatform` - The port to be used
  by the Platform JMX/RMI server.

In addtions you can configure the `useLocalPorts` attribute - Should any clients using these ports be forced to use local ports to connect to the the JMX/RMI server.
Notice that this listener requires `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` to be placed in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. This jar may be found in the extras directory of the binary download area.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I success to configure the listener, but...


It add 2 additional ports. Now I have 5 ports opened (and no one with `::ffff:127.0.0.1` while I use `useLocalPorts`).
Is it Tomcat bug?
List of ports:
`tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*           
tcp        0      0 :::10001                    :::*           
tcp        0      0 :::10002                    :::*           
tcp        0      0 :::34075                    :::*           
tcp        0      0 :::52288                    :::*           
tcp        0      0 :::9123                     :::*`

Comment: you can set the value of rmiBindAddress to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks, it effect on two ports that was configured in the JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.
Any case, it not effect on to additional random ports and I do not understand why they are opened (BTW, you can see that they are random - look on all lists).
Is it Tomcat bug? List of ports:
`tcp        0      0 :::40973                    
tcp        0      0 :::32814                    
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:10001      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:10002      
tcp        0      0 :::9123`

Comment: Not sure if this is a Tomcat issue. If you completely disable JMX do you see that the JVM is not listening to those random ports? btw, port 9123 seems to repeat itself

Comment: When I comment out JmxRemoteLifecycleListener and JMX settings listed in the question above I have only one port as expected: 
`tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*`

Comment: Port 9123 is configured via JMX and it is expected `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9123`.
BTW, it is Tomcat 7.0.47 and Java 1.7.0_45-b18

Comment: You should not configure the com.sun.management.jmxremote.port system property when using the JMX Remote Lifecycle Listener. The rmiRegistryPortPlatform attribute is replacing it. This might be the issue

Comment: It was improved!! Now I have only one random port (60714 in the list below) when I configure the following JmxRemoteLifecycleListener: 
`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
rmiRegistryPortPlatform="9123" rmiServerPortPlatform="10002" rmiBindAddress="localhost"/>`
Is it Tomcat bug? List of ports:
`tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*    
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:10002      :::*  
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:9123       :::*    
tcp        0      0 :::60714                            :::*`

Comment: This port seems to be related but I'm not sure what it used for. Trying the same setup on a Centos box I see that it is not being used when connecting with JConsole

Comment: This thread suggests that the third port is probably related to  RMI registry of the local only server : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035404