# How to configure what TLS version is used for JMX over SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, jmx, tls1.2

I need to configure TLSv1.2 for JMX communication.

Unfortunately I can not find the appropriate configuration here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

How to configure what TLS version is used for JMX over SSL?

PCI DSS 3.1 does not allow usage of TLS 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have obviously not read the documentation you have linked. It says:

1. `com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols`: Default SSL/TLS protocol version.
2. `com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites`: Default SSL/TLS cipher suites.

This should solve your problem. After you have configured that, scan your JXM port with [`sslscan`](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) with a recent version (1.0.2+) of OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it :)
May be you know how to bind JMX ports to localhost?
Now when you configure ports it listen to every IP.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699068/tomcat7-with-enabled-jmx-opens-2-additional-random-listening-ports

Comment: Have you tried the boolean value of `com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only`?

Comment: yes, but it is not bind. I still can not see `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Michael I am quite certain that there is a solution. All of my answers were found within 10 s of googling. You should be able to do so.

Comment: I have configured successfully `com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2` and it works great! (I will award the bounty tommorow - today is not possible). regarding localhost bunging: I spent couple of hours and was not able to find the way to bind it to localhost. when I configure `remote.port` I can not bind it to the localhost. If you know how to do it I will ask a new question with the new bounty.

Comment: @Michael. A new bounty is appropriate!